# Query executed, but data not saved into database PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql, json, post, mysqli

I'm trying to execute a SQL query that saves POST data into the database. The data comes in correctly, and the arrays that are coming with the POST data are converted to strings.

When the query gets executed the message 'Succesfully saved into database' appears, however the data isn't visible in the database, so there must be a little mistake inside my code, however I can't seem to find it.

See my code below:

```
//database connection file
require "includes/dbh.inc.php";

foreach ($_POST as $post_var){
  $obj = json_decode($post_var);

  //Convert arrays to string
  $userLikes = implode("|", $obj->userLikes);
  $userEvents = implode("|", $obj->userEvents);
  $userPosts = implode("|", $obj->userPosts);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO visitor_data (id, fb_id, name, location, likes, events, posts) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: dom.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();             
    }
    else {      
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $obj->userId, $obj->userName, $obj->userLocation, $userLikes, $userEvents, $userPosts);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        echo '<p>Succesfully saved into database</p>';
        exit();                            
          }    

}
```

[image]
This is how the database looks like

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try closing the "stmt" once you are done inserting rows.

Comment: The message appears because you print it, not because the query ran successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not assume that the query ran successfully because an exception was not thrown. You need to consider what the function returns and how many rows are affected before knowing if it ran successfully or not. Update your code to this and figure out what is going on:

Also check to make sure you are not just updating the same row over and over.

```
//database connection file
require "includes/dbh.inc.php";

foreach ($_POST as $post_var){
    $obj = json_decode($post_var);

    //Convert arrays to string
    $userLikes = implode("|", $obj->userLikes);
    $userEvents = implode("|", $obj->userEvents);
    $userPosts = implode("|", $obj->userPosts);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO visitor_data (id, fb_id, name, location, likes, events, posts) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: dom.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $obj->userId, $obj->userName, $obj->userLocation, $userLikes, $userEvents, $userPosts);
        if ( mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ) {
            echo '<p>Succesfully saved into database</p>';
        } else {
            printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) );
        }
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, with the error message I was able to resolve the problem.